# Need help determining how to approach building my project

Tags: javascript, database, web-applications, html

I'd like to create something similar to a family tree online app (like geni.com). I'm unsure what languages I should use to build it with. My IT strong points aren't in programming and this project is going to require me to sit down and learn some languages. My problem right now is that I don't know what languages I should use.

So with the idea of a family tree online app in mind here are some of the specifications. 
- I do not want to use flash. 
- The app needs to be zoomable and scrollable (sort of like google maps) 
- The app needs to be able to add content without reloading the page. Perhaps there's a little "+" sign and when I click it, I can add a tag/title/description/picture 
- The app needs to be able to save your work for that user to retrieve later on. 
- The layout that a user is able to create in is sort of widget based where the user can add a new bubble and then in that bubble they are able to add text or content.

I started programming this with HTML5 canvas and Javascript, but I'm stuck on creating a connection to the database that isn't directly from Javascript (because that seems very insecure to me). But I'm not just stumped on how to interact securely with the database (I don't even have a database picked out), but also I'm concerned that I won't be able to build out the app with just javascript and may need something else like ajax or something but I'm unfamiliar with what each language does nowadays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are starting from scratch, then the best language to use is the one *you* are most comfortable with. Alternately, if you don't plan to be developing the whole thing yourself **and you already have some other interested parties on board** then the best language to use is the one that the majority of you are comfortable with.  If it's just you and you do not yet have any favorites, then look around and play with a few - it's the **only** way to find out if you will actually like / be effective with them.

That being said, a few of the more likely candidates these days are:

- **JavaScript:** Long gone are the days when this language was simply a way to put the **D** in DHTML. These days JavaScript is a viable client **and** server-side language. (Others here have already recommended [Node.js](http://nodejs.org/) -- I'd also recommend [NPM (node package manager)](http://npmjs.org/) to handle your dependencies). With a little bit of planning you can reuse most of your application code on both the client and the server side.  On the downside, most of the server side technology is *very* new (only a few years old at most) and so you may find yourself implementing tools for use in your application rather than your application itself.  Finding servers that support it will also be harder, again on account of it's age.
- **Perl:** At the opposite end of the spectrum of age, we find Perl - the first commonly deployed language used to make web applications it *still* powers a great variety of useful websites out there (include new ones such as Pinboard.)  The tools that are popular on [CPAN](http://www.cpan.org/) have been vetted under **fire**. The good news is that it is not going anywhere anytime soon.  The bad news is, you might have to search a little harder to find a module that supports [**that newest, baddest thing that just came out yesterday**].
- **PHP:** The BASIC (or Perl, depending on who you ask) of the modern web, PHP was designed from the ground up to do one thing - make building dynamic web pages easier.  Its popularity means that there is quite a lot of server support (PHP + Apache + MySQL is the Model T Ford of web servers -- everyone can afford one) and an enormous amount of pre-built code available for perusal.  However, like BASIC, PHP's strength is also its greatest weakness.  Almost anyone can write something that *works* in PHP ... how well it works depends on who wrote it. The *caveat emptor* that applies to all code snippets found on the web applies in spades to snippets of code written in PHP.
- **Python:** The language that [made programing fun again](http://xkcd.com/353/) (at least for those who can see past the significant whitespace and lack of blocks / anonymous functions and overlook < 3.x's [issues with non-ASCII out of the box](http://farmdev.com/talks/unicode/).)  It's a general-purpose, [flexible](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#special-method-names) and [multi](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html)[-](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html)[paradigm](http://docs.python.org/library/functools.html) language with quite a substantial standard library (but without .NET or Java's incredible bloat).  In addition, quite a large amount of work has been done in it, so there is a good chance that what you need has been already developed by somebody else. Plus, [it can make you fly](http://xkcd.com/353/).
- **Ruby (with or without Rails):** The language that made the web fun, coupled, if you so desire, with [the framework that made MVC *cool*](http://rubyonrails.org/).  There is *lots* of documentation out there, and a great community, with many prebuilt tools (called [gems](http://rubygems.org/)) from which to pick and choose - free and cheap servers are not as common as their PHP counterparts, but they are likely to be of higher quality (when chosen at random).

All that being said, they are **all** great languages for web development. What matters is not what *we* think you *should* use ... but what you are most likely to be *effective* with.  All of the languages listed above are mainstream (or will be in the next two years), easy-to-learn and easy-to-write languages.  You cannot go wrong, no matter what you choose to start off with.

---

Alternately, if you want something a little more difficult, or less mainstream ... I am working with [.NET](http://www.microsoft.com/net/) applications at work, and with [Lisp (SBCL)](http://www.sbcl.org/)-based services in my spare time.  I have heard great things about Lua and Java too ... there are at least [two](http://cppcms.sourceforge.net/wikipp/en/page/main) [C++ web frameworks](http://www.webtoolkit.eu/wt) out there ... and I'm sure that there is *somebody* is having fun building a web service in COBOL with a FORTRAN backend. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

As someone has already pointed out, you will need to work with a server side language as well. (Ruby, Python, PHP)  You are exactly right there you should not be attempting a database connection via javascript in the browser.

You'll need to build out a server side application to handle the basic operations of your application.

I'd strongly recommend reading up on the MVC design pattern, and possibly looking into Ruby on Rails as your backend framework, it plays very nicely with ajax like features, and has a somewhat shorter learning curve, I believe, than some other frameworks / languages.

Answer (score 0):

You will need server side scripts in a language like [PHP](http://php.net/) or [Ruby on Rails](http://rubyonrails.org/) to interact with a database.

Comment: Ruby on Rails isn't a language. Ruby is. Ruby on Rails is a library for Ruby.

Answer (score 0):

If you're already familiar with HTML5 and JavaScript, may I recommend using [Node.JS](http://nodejs.org/)? It's about the closest you'll get to what you already know with browser development. It can also hook in with database systems which are closer to the HTML5-suggested [IndexedDB](http://www.w3.org/TR/IndexedDB/).

*with that in mind...*

If you're inexperienced with programming and programming languages, then the app you describe will involve a pretty big learning curve. While Flash and Flex have really nice interfaces to build apps with click-and-drag, the tools for HTML5 are much less mature.

That's not saying it's not possible with HTML5. Just that there's still some time to wait before people create tools to bring the app building process closer to what Adobe provides.